# jax-ws change or wrapp WSServlet

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, jax-ws, servlet-filters

We used the `jax-ws` standard to expose web services. The web services works fine.

Now we want to do some controls before the `jax-ws` servlet take the request and send the response. For example:

1. Disable `\servicename?wsdl` shows the `wsdl`
2. Disable `\servicename` shows service information table
3. Do not allow web service to be available for certain IP in certain time.

We have searched a lot and the only thing which we found is the `WSServlet` which is the entry point of all requests, but we don't know how it can be changed or wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class WSHandler
  implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>
{
///implement methods
}
```